# Битрикс Новости: созданное свойство не отображается при редактировании новости

Tags: битрикс

В настройках информационного блока Новости создал св-во. Стоит галка "Активно" и "Показывать на странице редактирования элемента", "Выводить поле для описания значения"(это уже в детальных настройках св-ва).

При добавлении новости поля св-ва нет.

Просьба не посылать в оф. поддержку Битрикс. Их "ответим через 3 дня" мне не нужно.

Comment: Какой тип свойства? Хорошо бы скриншот для корректного ответа (причем и вкладки "Свойства", и вкладки "Инфоблок".

Comment: Тип - строка. Пробовал еще тип текст. Пробовал галку "Обязательное".

Просто скажите на предмет чего надо проверить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не очень точный вопрос: если вы хотите видеть и править это свойство в админке при добавлении новости, то нужно сначала сделать Настройку панели редактирования, в ней добавить свойство (скрин).

[image: Настройка панели редактирования инфоблока Битрикс]

Разместить это свойство где нужно, а затем править.